# Javascript - use an array to calculate some coordinates

Tags: javascript, html

the line below will return some numbers in the format

`8458.268,19166.142,13113.780,25837.795,13113.780,25837.795...`

```
output=output.split("\n").filter(/./.test, /Coordinates/).join("\n").replace(/[^0-9.,]/g,'');
```

then it outputs in the line below... but before it outputs... I need to perform some calculations... like divide all those numbers by X

```
document.getElementById('inputTextToSave').innerHTML= output0 + output + output2;
```

Comment: Not clear what you're asking.

Comment: the numbers in an array need to be divided by 2.2 before output.. I don't know to create an array to perform the calculation

Comment: Post how the raw data really look like.

Comment: text file contains a line with:  Coordinates: (999.000,111.000,234.00,234.000....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a `map` function on the array at the point where you need to make the calculations. Once you have the array so that each item is in the format that you want, you can map through the array and divide each item by 2.2.

E.g.

```
arr.map((item) => {
  return item/2.2;
}) // at this point you could chain on 'join("\n")' or whatever
```

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to make an array out of the data you have, then perform a calculation on each piece of that data, and then do something else with it. If so, then the built in javascript `map` function is the way to go.

Note: I use ES6 fat arrow syntax for the function inside map, obviously you could just use an anonymous function with `map(function(item) {...});`

Comment: I tried using this but it will return NaN...       var array = ['output'];
        divBy2 = v => v / 2.2;
        result = array.map(divBy2);

Comment: try running `parseFloat()` on your item before dividing by 2.2. Eg `divBy2 = v => parseFloat(v) / 2.2;`

Comment: it works now and returns a value... but it only returns the first value from an array. i.e my array consists of 1,2,3,4,5,... it only returns the value of the first number.

Comment: What does your code look like now? It's working for me: `arr = [100, 200,34,2.2,65];` then running: `arr.map((item) => { return item/2.2 });` results in `[45.45, 90.90, 15.45, 1, 29.54]`. (note: I took out some of the decimals places)

Comment: number actually come from a text file... I'm using output below to extract..  
                                var array = [output];
        divBy2 = v => parseInt(v) / 2;
        result = array.map(divBy2);

Comment: output=output.split("\n").filter(/./.test, /coordinates/).join("\n").replace(/[^0-9.,]/g,'');

Comment: document.getElementById('inputTextToSave').innerHTML= output0 + result

Comment: Don't put `output` inside `[]`, that's why you only have one item to map over. Is output already an array? Did you `console.log` output and array to see what they are?

Comment: yes output without an array map returns fine... yes, output is an array... I did not console.log it... how do I do? thanks

Comment: Great if that is working please upvote and accept the answer. To answer your other question, run `console.log(output)` and then open up the console in the browser to see what it says - this is a good way to see what values you're working with. Also there is no need to write `var array = output;` you could just write `output.map(divBy2);`

Comment: yes. console.log(output) returns 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, in the browser.

Comment: how do I upvote and accept the answer?... sorry first time here.

Comment: See the up and down arrows to the left of my answer, click the up arrow, when you hover over there you should also see a green tick, click on it to accept the answer.

Comment: i have to output in this format:::   document.getElementById('inputTextToSave').innerHTML= output0 + result